# Why does QLPreviewPanel handle event twice?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have some images to make the `QLPreviewPanel` display.I set the `QLPreviewPanel`'s delegate.
This is my code

```
    - (BOOL)previewPanel:(QLPreviewPanel *)panel handleEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{

    unsigned short tmpKeyCode = [event keyCode];

    if (tmpKeyCode == 123 || tmpKeyCode == 124 || tmpKeyCode ==125 || tmpKeyCode == 126) {
        NSLog(@"previewPanel arrow key event");
        [self.collectionView keyDown:event];
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

When I trigger the arrow key event,I find that this delegate method is called twice.Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have known the answer of this question.The event param contains two type,one is `keyDown` and the other is `keyUp`.So I just handle only one of the two type.It looks like easy.